# TypeError: unbound method when i am returning a page object from my log in method

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am reorganizing my webdriver, python framework which I have recently started.
Scenario:  I log into our website from the LoginPage Class calling the userLogin_valid method (this logs in a valid user)
I have changed this method to return Main Dashboard Page object because when user logs in the main page dashboard is shown.
From here I can click Administration tab, Data Configuration tab etc.

From my DataConfigurationPage_TestCase I call the user login method as follows:

```
data_configuration_page = self.login_page.userLogin_valid("userName", "pass")
```

I then call the click data configuration button from the Main Dashboard Page class as follows (From Main Dashboard page I click the Data Configuration tab):

```
data_configuration_page.click_data_configuration() # Click Data Configuration from menu bar
```

I am getting the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\riaz.ladhani\PycharmProjects\Selenium Webdriver\ClearCore 501 - Copy\TestCases\DataConfigurationPage_TestCase.py", line 30, in test_add_Data_Objects
    data_configuration_page.click_data_configuration() # Click Data Configuration from menu bar
TypeError: unbound method click_data_configuration() must be called with MainDashboardPage instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

Some help appreciated to what I am doing wrong here to get this error.
I am doing something wrong with calling the page objects.

My code snippet as follows:

Pages\login.py

```
import time
import Locators
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from Locators.element import BasePageElement
from Locators.locators import MainPageLocators
from Locators import locators
from Locators import element
from Locators.element import BasePageElement
from Pages.admin import AdministrationPage
from Pages.base import BasePage
from Pages.main_dashboard import MainDashboardPage
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


class LoginPage(BasePage):

    def userLogin_valid(self, name, password):
        _name = name
        _password = password
        userName_textbox = self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.usernameTxtBox)
        userName_textbox.clear()
        userName_textbox.send_keys(_name)
        password_textbox = self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.passwordTxtBox)
        password_textbox.clear()
        password_textbox.send_keys(_password)
        submitButton = self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.submitButton)
        submitButton.click()
        return MainDashboardPage
```

Pages\main_dashboard.py

```
import time
import datetime
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from Locators.locators import MainPageLocators
from Locators.element import BasePageElement
from Pages.base import BasePage

class MainDashboardPage(BasePage):

    def click_data_configuration(self):
        self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.DataConfiguration_button_xpath).click()
        return MainDashboardPage(self.driver)
```

TestCases\DataConfigurationPage_TestCase.py

```
import unittest
import time
import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
from Locators import locators
from Locators import element
from Pages import login
from Pages import admin
from Pages import main_dashboard


class AdministrationPage_TestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.INTERNETEXPLORER["unexpectedAlertBehaviour"] = "accept"
        self.driver = webdriver.Ie("C:\QA\Automation\Python_projects\Selenium Webdriver\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.45.0\IEDriverServer.exe")
        self.driver.get("http://riaz-pc.company.local:8080/clearcore")
        self.login_page = login.LoginPage(self.driver)
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)

    def test_add_Data_Objects(self):
        print "*** test_add_Data_Objects ***"
        data_configuration_page = self.login_page.userLogin_valid("batman", "batarang123")
        data_configuration_page.click_data_configuration() # Click Data Configuration from menu bar
        assert data_configuration_page.is_Data_Configuration_pageDisplayed(), "Data Configuration Page not displayed"
        print "data_configuration_page.is_Data_Configuration_pageDisplayed()"
        print data_configuration_page.is_Data_Configuration_pageDisplayed()




    def tearDown(self):
        self.login_page.click_logout()
        self.driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `login_page.userLogin_valid(self, name, password)` returns a class not an instance of the class.

Comment: return MainDashboardPage is returning a class?  If i do return new MainDashboardPage() it does not work in Python.  I think in C# new classname() would return an instance of the class.

Comment: I am going to try return MainDashboardPage()

Comment: Thanks! My test runs further now.  I now get a different error:  TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: I am going to try return MainDashboardPage(self)

Comment: Try return MainDashboardPage(self.driver) like in click_data_configuration(self).